# How to format decimal number to custom format in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, decimal

I want to convert decimal number to specific format.

```
FROM 123456789.1234 to 12,34,56,789.00.
```

I tried it using

```
SELECT FORMAT(123456789.1234, 'N', 'en-us') as 'en-us'
```

but this returns:

```
123,456,789.12
```

I also tried

```
SELECT FORMAT(123456789.1234, '##,###.00') as 'en-us'
```

and got the same result.

Any suggestions on this?

Comment: do you really mean this format `12,34,56,789.00`? maybe you mean `123,456,789.00`.

Comment: OK, I'll say it ... Formatting really belongs in the presentation layer.

Comment: `##\,##\,##\,###\.\0\0`?

Comment: @shawnt, if number is 123 only, above format will show somthing ,,123.00.

Comment: @John Woo, I need 12,34,56,789.00 only

Comment: I was aware but you only gave one example. Perhaps it's still easier to lop off those leading commas than alternate solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ROUND` OR `FLOOR` function with `FORMAT` function -

```
SELECT FORMAT(ROUND(123456789.1234,0), 'N', 'en-IN') as 'Round',
       FORMAT(FLOOR(123456789.1234), 'N', 'en-IN') as 'Floor'
```

Please check difference between `Round` and `Floor` function.

Comment: Was waiting for someone to offer something other than round()

Comment: @BhatiaAshish - round or floor is not my primary goal. My goal is to achieve number separators. above solution gives me - Round 1234,56,789.00,Floor 1234,56,789.00 ,  which did not help me.

Comment: @NishantRana, Above query gives me 12,34,56,789.00 which is as per requirement. Not sure why this not working on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to do this would probably be `Round()`

```
SELECT FORMAT(ROUND(123456789.1234,0), 'N', 'en-us') as 'en-us'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try round() in inner side. you also want "12,34,56,789.00" format. So, for that you can change regional setting of your machine.

Answer (score 0):

If, you don't want to use decimal values you could simply cast them as *INT/BIGINT*

```
SELECT FORMAT(cast(123456789.1234 as bigint), 'N', 'en-In')
```

Use culture parameter `en-In` for Indian Numbering system instead of Western Numbering system `en-us` 
[look for Numbering system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_numbering_system)

Comment: This doen't help me exactly with my requirement. I need to show 12,56,789. Above is showing me 1234,56,789

Comment: @NishantRana.. what SQL Version u r using ?

Comment: SQL Server 2012

Comment: @NishantRana... make sure your culture parameter has value of `en-In` instead of  `en-us`.

Answer (score 0):

```
replace(ltrim(format(d, '## ## ## ## ###\.\0\0')), ' ', ',')
```